# Why the water hasn't the right strenght to reach and to fall at the end of the road?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I'm playing with the fluid simulation and I want to reach this [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNaubFVVY1Y1bTExLVE/). Instead,this is the [result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_vrhf_PTNauUjRxSm9FSGY2YlU) that I get. In short words,the water hasn't the right strenght to reach and to fall at the end of the road but it falls on the way. What's wrong ? thanks.

[blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauSWc5VFlneURqRjA/)

Comment: Could you provide a blend file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauSWc5VFlneURqRjA/

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend file uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your file.

1. Your pipe obstacle has wrong normals. The solidify modifier is applied only after the fluid simulation (see the order of modifiers), so the simulation is done using only the inner shell with flipped normals. Remove the fluid obstacle modifier, apply the solidify (check normals) and add the obstacle again.
2. Your inflow is highly suboptimal. Not only is it inside of the pipe, I would recommend an inflow plane altogether (if so, switch to shell)
   [image]
3. The inflow has very weird inflow velocities They should point in negative y direction (and from some tests, they should have much smaller values).

Comment: check this please : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauRVEwcVBqV2VlLW8/ and tell me what's wrong. It does not work,I tried to do exactly what you said,but the fluid simulation does not start at all.

Comment: I did everything again,but still does not work. Check here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_vrhf_PTNaud1dpOTZwMTFzRE0

Comment: blender file attached here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauSE11eHYxYjhIUDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: honestly I'm a bit puzzled myself and I don't have time to look into it deeply. Maybe someone else has an idea? Sorry about that.

Comment: the solution was to create more space between the slipway and the pipe and to choose "unit presets = none"